# Paging in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: list, paging

How to show on the list Paging button with last element. LLast site, because when I have got 500 elements for examle i must click about 15 times before i see last added element. Is there any button wchich show last page with near aded element. I know it can be done by show all elements on a list, but then a list is soo big, and work slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a different view and order it descending from the created date field. You can create multiple views on SharePoint lists. Then group by date if you need much summarized information. Just 5 minute work.

Comment: But then I can't put this view on a page.

Comment: So how do you need that to be displayed? you can set it as default view.

Comment: But where can I put button, wchich can change the view?

Comment: You can add hyperlinks to different pages which have different views.

Comment: But where and how ? upseirs on link?

Comment: There will be no buttons that can change the view. What I am saying is create 2 pages + content editor where 2 links for each page + 2 list view webparts with a different view in each. In each page, add 1 content editor web part + list view. So you can navigate whenever needed.